# How to change a drive statement

Tags: python, selenium

I have a driver statement that I want to use over and over but change one of the variables.

I want to add a 1 to the variable each time it passes.

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*@id="js_proList"]/ul[1]/li[1]/div/div/p""").click()
```

I want to change the /li[1] to /li[2] then /li[3] .....

Comment: Do you want to iterate through all the `li`s in the list `ul`, or only specific set?

Answer (score 2):

You need to format your string to take a variable where you want to change the value, and loop over a list of the values you want it to change by:

```
myList = ["1", "2", "3"]

for value in myList:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="js_proList"]/ul[1]/li[{}]/div/div/p""".format(value)).click()
```

If you'd like to count up, use `range()`.

```
for value in range(1, 4):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="js_proList"]/ul[1]/li[{}]/div/div/p""".format(value)).click()
```

Comment: If take the for statement off it works, so I know the xpath is ok.             I keep getting:             InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*@id="js_proList"]/ul[1]/li[1]/div/div/p because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*@id="js_proList"]/ul[1]/li[1]/div/div/p' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.100)

Comment: Your xpath was missing the left bracket on the first element. I updated the xpath.

Answer (score 0):

use loop:

```
x = 1 
for i in range(y):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*@id="js_proList"]/ul[1]/li[{}]/div/div/p""".format(x)).click()
    x += 1
```

Comment: Do you change the y to the limit you want the range?

Comment: yes, if **y = 2** loop will do what need to do 2 times.